# Terraform: Getting volume_id from aws_instance resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is it possible with terraform to get the volume ID from the `aws_instance` ebs_block_device resource, or would we need to explicitly call the `aws_ebs_volume`/`aws_volume_attachment` resources?

What I currently have is:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_app" {
...
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name           = "${var.app_ebs_device_name}"
    volume_type           = "${var.app_ebs_vol_type}"
    volume_size           = "${var.app_ebs_vol_size}"
    delete_on_termination = "${var.app_ebs_delete_on_termination}"
    encrypted             = "${var.app_ebs_encrypted}"
  }
...
}
```

I know I can change to `aws_ebs_volume`/`aws_volume_attachment` resources, but I believe that would destroy and recreate the volume (which I am trying to avoid).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are a little bit misleading on this point, but you can get the volume id of the ebs_block_device like this:

```
"${lookup(aws_instance.example.ebs_block_device[0], "volume_id")}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you have created a volume as follow:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs-volume-1" {
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
    size = 8
    type = "gp2"
    tags {
        Name = "extra volume data"
    }
```

You can get the volume ID by specifying

```
volume_id = "${aws_ebs_volume.ebs-volume-1.id}"
```

Comment: that's not the question OP is asking. If you have an ec2 instance ID, can you get attached volume id?

Comment: @innocent-anigbo What I currently have is:
`resource "aws_instance" "resource_name" {
.....
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name           = "${var.indexer_ebs_device_name}"
    volume_type           = "${var.indexer_ebs_vol_type}"
    volume_size           = "${var.indexer_ebs_vol_size}"
    delete_on_termination = "${var.indexer_ebs_delete_on_termination}"
    encrypted             = "${var.indexer_ebs_encrypted}"
  }
...
}
`

Is there anyway to get that ebs volume ID from that, other than changing to what you are saying (which I believe would destroy and recreate the volume)?